# java.lang.NullPointerException in a strange situation

Tags: hibernate, jsp, nullpointerexception

I'm having a really weird situation. I am calling a `hibernate` function for reading an entry from the DB, and it works in the most of the places where I call it, but in just one place, it's not working, giving me `NullPointerException`. I think something really small is missing in the code but I don't know what it is. Take a look here:

The `Servlet` in which I call the function:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String dataA = request.getParameter("answers");
        String dataQ = request.getParameter("quests");
        String user = request.getParameter("usern");
        String chap = request.getParameter("chapt");

        String[] answers = dataA.split(",");
        String[] quests = dataQ.split("&");


        TestHandler tHandler = new TestHandler(5);
        UserDAO u=new UserDAO();
        UserChapterDAO uc = new UserChapterDAO();


        ChapterDAO chdao = new ChapterDAO();
        Chapter myCh=chdao.findTChapter(chap+"");

        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println(chap);
        out.println(myCh.getId());
```

The hibernate method:

```
 @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public Chapter findTChapter(String title) {

            List<Chapter> chapter = null;
            Transaction tx=null;

              try{
                    Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
                    SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();
                    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
                    tx = session.beginTransaction();

                Query query = session.createQuery("FROM Chapter WHERE title = :title");
                query.setParameter("title", title);
                chapter = query.list();
                tx.commit();
            } catch (HibernateException e) {
                if (tx != null) {
                    tx.rollback();
                }
                LOGGER.error("", e);
            } 

              return chapter != null && !chapter.isEmpty() ? chapter.get(0) : null;
        }
```

Error trace:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [TestServlet] in context with path [/HibernateWebApp] threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at controller.TestServlet.doPost(TestServlet.java:76)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1115)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The servlet mapping is the following one:

```
<servlet>
    <display-name>Test</display-name>
    <servlet-name>TestServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>controller.TestServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>TestServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/test</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

And the jsp part which calls the servlet:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="test" method="POST">

                        <div class="form-group">
                         <input type="hidden" id="answers" name="answers">
                         <input type="hidden" id="quests" name="quests" value="<%out.println(q); %>" >  
                         <input type="hidden" id="chatp" name="chapt" value="<%out.println(request.getParameter("chapter")); %>">   
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-md" id="finish" style="display:none;">Finish</button>

                            </div>
                        </form>
```

The error apears at **out.println(myCh.getId())** , so id doesn't actually read a Chapter from DB and store in myCh object.
I mention that in other places where I'm using this, it works perfectly. Also, if I call the function by hard-coding the String chap into the actual String, it is working. And I'm also sure that the String chap is perfectly taken from the jsp, as I print it with out.println(chap) and it's what it has to be.

I'm really stuck in there. Any ideas?

Comment: `Chapter myCh=chdao.findTChapter(chap+"");` 



can you confirm whether you receive **null** value for `myCh`
if you could print `chap` and gets **null** value for `myCh`,  you need to debug ur `findTChapter` method.

Comment: yes, it is null, i cheked it

Comment: So, `chap` has value and `findTChapter` returns null?

Comment: exactly, chap has the right value(I print it and it's the right one) and findTChapter returns null. If I hardcode the parameter of the call and instead of chap I wrote the actual String, it is working.

Comment: Could you please post your servlet mapping file?

Comment: Just added it in the question, together with the jsp form which calls the servlet

Comment: Added my comment in answer section. Confirm if that works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
Query query = session.createQuery("FROM Chapter c WHERE c.title = :title");
```

Comment: It gives me the same thing :( really believe there is no problem with the hibernate function though, as It is working in the rest of the cases

Answer (score 0):

First thing:
`String chap = request.getParameter("chapt");`

Change it to:
`String chap = request.getParameter("chapter");`

Also confirm whether your action url is in the form:
**http://appurl/test?chapter=abcd**

Comment: Yes, the url has that form with the needed chapter. Also, changing the request parameters is giving me the same result. So weird

Comment: Whether your exception goes off when comment this line:




`<input type="hidden" id="chatp" name="chapt" value="<%out.println(request.getParameter("chapter")); %>"> `  ??

like you can test and confirm by giving hardcoded values there.

Comment: same thing. I just deleted that input and tried only to read the url param. Also, putting the input as text, its value is the right one as well

Comment: If changing request parameter for `chapter` is giving you same result, I would like to understand which one of the below throws error:
`<%out.println(q); %>`   or    `<%out.println(request.getParameter("chapter")); %>`

Comment: Also what about this:
`        String dataA = request.getParameter("answers");
        String dataQ = request.getParameter("quests");
        String user = request.getParameter("usern"); `

Whether any of this(dataA/dataQ/user) brings null value?

Comment: Neither, there is no error in the jsp file. The error is thrown in servlet, at this line:`out.println(myCh.getId());`

Comment: Please put hardcoded value for `title` inside `findTChapter` method and see whether you still get exception.

Comment: having this call:
`ChapterDAO chdao = new ChapterDAO();
  Chapter myCh=chdao.findTChapter("Media Aritmetica");` with the hardcoded value, bring me the desired result

Comment: it may not be the lead, but let me know why it was written:
`findTChapter(chap+"");`  while it could be written like this:
`findTChapter(chap);`

Comment: yeah, I added "" after just to make sure it reads a String there (just to try everything it can be done haha) HAving it without "" is the same...

Comment: I would want you to print on console `out.println("a"+chap+"a");` to see whether there's a trailing space at the beginning or at the end of variable `chap`.

Comment: yeap! this solved haha, it had a blank space after it which I didnt notice while printing it or puttin it inside an input text. Gosh! Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Typo. You have

```
String chap = request.getParameter("chapt");
```

but

```
<input type="hidden" id="chatp" name="chapt" value="<%out.println(request.getParameter("chapter")); %>">
```

Try to get your ids and names and parameter names to agree.

Comment: it got the parameter right haha, regardless the typo :)